# How to categorify entropy/perplexity?

Tags: ct.category-theory, entropy

(Migrating from [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4545709/322566) per commenter suggestion)

I was reading Baez, Fritz, and Leinster's "[A Characterization of Entropy in Terms of Information Loss](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1791)", and wondered if, instead of working in $\mathbf{FinMeas}$, we could work in any (e.g.) [regular category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+category), by categorifying conditional entropy. Actually, it seems easier to categorify perplexity (exponential entropy), which eliminates the logarithm and its arbitrary base.

The [perplexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity) of a probability distribution $p$ is $$PP(p)=\frac{1}{\prod_x{p_x}^{p_x}}$$

In $\textbf{Grp}$, the above formula seems to suggest defining the [conditional] perplexity of a morphism $f$ as something like $\operatorname{End}(\operatorname{ker}(f))$. My vague intuition is that the kernel is what is lost by $f$, and its endomorphism monoid determines its information content since any morphism in $\textbf{Grp}$ factors into an endomorphism followed by a monomorphism.

However, even if $\operatorname{End}(\operatorname{ker}(f))$ happens to be the right way to define perplexity in $\textbf{Grp}$, maybe it only works because the cosets of a kernel are all isomorphic, and if we want it to work more generally we'd need to do something like $\frac{\operatorname{End}(\operatorname{dom} f)}{\operatorname{End}(\operatorname{im} f)}$, if that even makes sense.

Does anyone have any insights as to the "right" way to categorify entropy/perplexity, or any references that might be helpful?

A bonus question is: why is entropy so much more popular than perplexity? Do people just like addition more than multiplication? Historical accident? It's a bit...confusing.

Comment: concerning the bonus question: see https://mathoverflow.net/q/398217/11260

Comment: Sorry for the self-promotion, but since you ask for references, I wrote a book on just this sort of thing: "Entropy and diversity: the axiomatic approach" (free online version available: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/ed/). I hadn't heard the term "perplexity" before today; in my book, it's referred to as diversity of order 1.